# What is the difference between a QML component and a QML object type?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

[Qt's doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtqml-component.html#details), says that :

> Components are reusable, encapsulated QML types with well-defined
>   interfaces.
>
> Components are often defined by component files - that is, .qml files.
>   The Component type essentially allows QML components to be defined
>   inline, within a QML document, rather than as a separate QML file.

What is the meaning of "*encapsulated QML types with well-defined interfaces"* ?

Also when it comes to define a new QML object type, from [Qt's doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html) we have :

> To create an object type, a QML document should be placed into a text
>   file named as TypeName.qml where TypeName is the desired name of
>   the type

So what is the difference between a QML component and a QML object type ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

in [this](https://www.ics.com/files/qtdocs/qml-extending-types.html) document they call **custom** objects as component.

A component is a reusable type with a well-defined interface, built entirely in QML. Any snippet of QML code can become a component, by placing the code in a file ".qml" where  is the new component name, beginning with an uppercase letter. These QML files automatically become available as new QML **element** (object) types to other QML components and applications in the same directory.

**custom object type and component are the same but object like rectangle isn't  component .**
**whenever you create a custom object with TypeName.qml file , engin loads the TypeName.qml document as a component.**

we have 2 kind of component:

1. defined by component file - that is, .qml files. so we can say this kind of component is same as qml document.
2. The Component type essentially allows QML components to be defined inline, within a QML document, rather than as a separate QML file.

in [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-topic.html) document they say :

An instance of the **object type** defined by a document may be created using a **Component** in QML code, or a **QQmlComponent** in C++. Alternatively, if the object type is explicitly exposed to the QML type system with a particular type name, the type may be used directly in object declarations in other documents.

so if you create a custom object type you actually create a component and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the meaning of "encapsulated QML types with well-defined interfaces" ?

To me, the encapsulated part means that the QML contained in the component is self-contained and hence can be reused. The well-defined part means that only the properties defined in the root object of the component can be accessed by outside code, similar to how you would use the `protected` and `private` keywords in C++.

> So what is the difference between a QML component and a QML object type ?

My understanding of what the documentation is saying is that a Component that is declared inline can't be instantiated in the same manner [1]. For example:

```
Component {
    id: myComponent

    Text {
        text: "Hello"
    }
}
```

You can use `myComponent` as e.g. a delegate:

```
ListView {
    // ...
    delegate: myComponent
}
```

But you can't use it to directly instantiate the type it represents:

```
myComponent {
    // ...
}
```

That's why you need to move the component into its own file (a "QML Object Type"):

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Text {
    text: "Hello"
}
```

Assuming you named the file MyType.qml, you can directly instantiate the type like this:

```
MyType {
    text: "Some text"
}
```

[1] As of Qt 5.15, it will be possible to instantiate components inline. See [this section](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html#inline-components) once 5.15 is released.